# java easy Regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have strings like "`xxxxx?434334`", "`xxx?411112`", "`xxxxxxxxx?11113`" and so on.

How to `substring` properly to retrieve "`xxxxx`" (everything that comes untill '`?`' character)?

Comment: If you like to use ``substring`` then why the question tagged in ``RegEx`` category?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
str = str.replaceAll("[?].*", "");
```

In other words, "remove everything after, and including, the question mark character". The `?` has to be enclosed in square brackets because otherwise it has a special meaning.

Comment: This retrieves everything AFTER `?`.

Comment: It seems that the question asks to retrieve prefix?

Comment: @khachik: You're right, I somehow managed to misread the question. Answer fixed.

Comment: Yeah,maybe I wrote it little bit ambiguous. Thanks you!

Answer (score 6):

```
return s.substring(0, s.indexOf('?'));
```

No need for a regex for that.

*If you have a problem, use a regex. Now you have two problems.*

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with others answers that you should avoid using regex wherever possible, but if you did want to use it for this scenario you could use the following

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("([^\\?]*)\\?{1}");
Matcher m = regex.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    result = m.group(1);
}
```

where str is your input string.

EDIT: 
Description of regex match any group of characters that are not a "?" and have a single "?" after the group

Answer (score 0):

The Pattern ".*(?=\?)" should work as well. ?= is a positive lookahead, which means the mattern matches everything that comes before a quotation mark, but not the quotation mark itself.